# TypeError: this.props.setProductBrand is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

When i click the update button the error occures. I am passing setProductBrand func. to productBrand Component.

**ProductBrand.Js**

```
<td>
    <Button onClick={() => this.props.setProductBrand(brand.productBrandId)} color="info">Güncelle</Button>
</td>
```

**App.js**

```
setProductBrand = (brand) => this.setState({ selectedBrand: brand });

<Route exact path='/ürünMarkası' setProductBrand={this.setProductBrand} component={ProductBrand} />
```

Comment: the definition of `setProductBrand ` should be in `this.props`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only passing `setProductBrand` prop to the `Route` component. `Route` components won't pass extra props on to rendered components. Use the `render` prop for this.

```
<Route
  exact
  path='/ürünMarkası'
  render={routeProps => (
    <ProductBrand setProductBrand={this.setProductBrand} {...routeProps} />
  )}
/>
```

If `ProductBrand` doesn't care about the route props then it can be simply rendered as a child of the `Route.

```
<Route
  exact
  path='/ürünMarkası'
>
  <ProductBrand setProductBrand={this.setProductBrand} />
</Route>
```

Comment: @YunusEmreCebe Welcome. Good luck and cheers, mate.